Vertex AI Agent Builder Datasource import notification
I'm new to vertex AI and currently i have this requirement to send SMS notification on datastore import success. I already have the cloud function program to send SMS for several people. The idea is to invoke the cloud function based on eventarc. Is it possible or any suggestions?
I have tried to check all of my loggings for the event type and none of them give the correct result.
